# How can I get the max value for each column?

Tags: postgresql, max

If data of table like this,

```
[co1:varchar][col2:varchar][col3:varchar][col4:timestamp]
```

And, Follow is data example.

```
224 / 755 / 542 / 2019-05-23 10:12:23
230 / 741 / 530 / 2019-05-23 10:12:23
221 / 769 / 567 / 2019-05-23 10:12:23
230 / 794 / 521 / 2019-05-23 10:12:23
...
```

I want to get one row with max value of each column for the same time rows.
Like,

230 / 768 / 542 / 2019-05-23 10:12:23

how can I do for It?

Comment: why are numbers in varchar columns? I assumed you want a numerical maximum.

Comment: Have you tried the `max()` function?

Comment: What queries have you tried? It should take too much into a tutorial to find and answer here.

Comment: **Never** store numbers in `varchar` columns.

Comment: Of course, I did not design this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be as simple as using `max()` on every column:

```
select max(col1), max(col2), max(col3), max(col4)
from the_table;
```

However, due to your wrong data design, you have to cast the varchar values to a number before you can do that:

```
select max(col1::integer), max(col2::integer), max(col3::integer), max(col4)
from the_table;
```

Note that this will fail if you accidentally stored something in those columns that isn't actually a number.